Trainees sent to an island and murdered
I saw this movie 2 years back and now I don't remember the name. I tried searching it on Youtube also but due to lack of information that I have I am unable to find it.
It was a Hollywood movie in which a group of people (for training) was sent to a lonely island. Then each person was murdered one by one but nobody was able to identify who the murderer was. At the end the murderer was one of the persons in the group.

are you sure it was an island? Predators had this basic plot.http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1424381/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2

It sounds similar to The Condemned (2007).

Could be Renny Harlin's thriller Mindhunters from 2004 with Christian Slater. From Wiki:

The titular Mindhunters are a group of young FBI students who are undergoing training as profilers. They travel with their instructor Jake Harris (Val Kilmer) to a small island off the coast of North Carolina to complete a profiling exercise. The island is used as a training facility by the FBI and the military where a mock town has been constructed. Harris has arranged an elaborate training scenario for his students to create a profile of a serial killer who has committed a murder in the town.

The scenario soon turns real and they are killed one by one, and the killer ends up being one of them. The full movie is currently available on Youtube, and here's the trailer:



